# coverting multiple sentences to positions

Tags: python

i have created a set of code which can convert the sentence into a list of positions.

```
sentence = "ask not what you can do for your country ask what your country can do for you"
d = {}
i = 0
values = []
for i, word in enumerate(sentence.split(" ")):
    if not word in d:
        d[word] = (i + 1)
    values += [d[word]]
print(values)
```

i now need for the program to be able to convert multiple sentences
so it would be

```
sentence = ("ask not what you can do for your country ask what your country can do for you")
sentence2 = ("some people enjoy computing others do not enjoy computing")
sentence3 = ("i will use this as my last sentence as i do not need another sentence")
```

i need the code to be able to create seperate lists for each of the sentences, without the code being too heavily modified

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a function:

```
def get_positions(sentence):
    d = {}
    i = 0
    values = []
    for i, word in enumerate(sentence.split(" ")):
        if not word in d:
            d[word] = (i + 1)
        values += [d[word]]
    return values

print get_positions(sentence1)
print get_positions(sentence2)
print get_positions(sentence3)
```

What this does is create a function that takes a sentences as an argument and then converts that into the list you wanted to construct. Any time you want to get the positions for a sentence you can just call your function with the sentence you want to get the positions for as the argument.

Note that I changed the print at the end of your code to a return value. the return statement is what comes back out of the function when you use it. Basically, you pass in some value, do some computation and then spit out another value.